# Program to remove all the consecutive same letter from a given string

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, aptitude

I am trying to develop a logic that will remove all the adjacent duplicate characters from a string.
For example:-
      **Input**:  azxxzy
      **Output**: ay

Here is the logic that I have developed in C:

```
int main()
{
  char str1[10], str2[10];
  int n, i=0, j=0,z=1, k=0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    gets(str1);
    str2[0]=str1[0];
    for(j=1; str1[j]!='\0'; j++){
        if(str1[j] == str1[j-1])
            continue;
        else
            str2[z] = str1[j];
        z++;
  }

  for(k=0; str2[k]!='\0'; k++)
      printf("%s\n", str2[k]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

While executing the code it is throwing a compile error. What might be the problem?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is this `#include #include` at the top of the file?

Comment: This looks like C code. If you compile as C++, change the tag, but don't add tags for a different, unrelated language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%s\n",str2[k]);
```

str2[k] is a char, but you tell printf it is a char*

But this program still will not work properly - the first call to gets() will just read the carriage-return that is left in the input queue after reading the initial int value. And you never null-terminate str2.